# .NET 4.0 MEF. Pluggable ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am going to start new MVC 3.0 .NET 4.0 application.

I want to implement each component for my web site once and simply reuse it then for another web sites i going to build.

Currently i am looking the best practice i can use to achieve my goal.

I did some research and found that I may get a lot of advantages using MEF.

I found interesting MEF MVC solution called plugable MVC http://www.thegecko.org/index.php/2010/06/pluggable-mvc-2-0-using-mef-and-strongly-typed-views.

Is it really worth to use such kind of approach(Plugabble MVC) of building MVC apps?

Advantages disadvantages of pluggable MVC?

May be somebody may suggest something else?

Comment: This is quite an old question but [this blog post](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=259) covers a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

What specific problem are you trying to solve? MVC is a very extensible and pluggable framework as it is. I would say that for a simple site MEF is not necessary. Please provide more information on the issues you are running into with the stock MVC framework.

Comment: I just want to implement each component once (e.g authentication, blog, registration etc) to be able simply reuse it. Looks like if i choose this approach(plugable MVC) i could achieve such result.